# Can one define shorthands for unicode ranges?

Tags: regular-expression

I have this
`\(\w[^\w\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff]*\)\([\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff][^\w]*[\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff]\)\([^\w]*\w\)`,
which I need to improve, but it is getting uncomfortably complicated; is it possible to define shorthands for expressions that are reused, such as `\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff`? or is there some other way to make this easier to work with?

Comment: The Perl way would be to use `(?<group-num>)`. Looking through `:h regex`, there's no Vim equivalent. How are you using this pattern? You could build it from variables, depending on how you use it.

Comment: @muru, how can I reference variables in a `/` search? if I `:let pat = "testpattern"` and `/pat()`, vim searches for "pat()", not "testpattern".

Comment: I am using the pattern to enclose Greek passages in `\gr{…}`. `:%s//\1\\gr{\2}\3`. I need to improve it to include cases where a line begins or ends with Greek, and maybe where Gr. spans over a few lines.

Comment: I seem to recall that Vim doesn't support ranges for multibyte characters.  I may be wrong though; perhaps ask on `vim_dev`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I read that too, but it does work.

Comment: It work in _some_ situations.  The effect is undefined in others, f.i. Vim might crash after a while.  I think one of the problematic situations is when the bounds of a range are more than 256 apart (actually when their byte representations differ in more than the last byte).  It actually makes sense if you think of it for a moment.  Still, it might no longer crash in recent versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a variable holding your pattern like this:
`:let g:pat='...'`
(Note the use of single quotation marks, to prevent side-effects).

Then you can search for that variable like this:
`:%s/<C-R>=g:pat<cr>/replacement_part/g` This is described at `:h c_CTRL-R_=`
or possibly easier:
`:exe '%s/'.g:pat.'/replacement/g'` (you could also wrap this in a `printf()` call)